# 2 div with fixed and liquid height in absolute positioned div

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/u0398kc1/2/

html

```
<div class="InfoPanel">
    <div class="Header">Header</div>
    <div class="Content">
        START<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>END<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.InfoPanel 
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.Header 
{
    height:30px; line-height:30px;
    background:#c1c1c1;
}

.Content 
{
    overflow:auto; height:100%;
    background:#f1f1f1;
}
```

"Header" div with fixed height are moving "Content" div so we dont see "END" string. Any solution without js?

1 solution is to make both Header and Content div liquid height, for example 10% and 90%. In my case it is unsuitable.

Comment: You can use `height: calc(100vh - 30px)` for `.Content` class. Browser compatibility for [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Im not really sure what you want to archive since info in the question is scarse, but removing overflow: hidden; shows the END string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 calc function:

```
.Content 
{
    overflow:auto; 
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    background:#f1f1f1;
}
```

For older browser support you should also include:

```
/* Firefox */
height: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
/* WebKit */
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
/* Opera */
height: -o-calc(100% - 30px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce `height` of `.Content` to make the content visible.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/reluyopixa/1/edit?html,css,output)**

```
.Content 
{
    overflow:auto; 
    height:96%; /* based on height of header */
    background:#f1f1f1;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

to make it look more generic to match all screen heights:

```
 height : calc(100% - 30px);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `.InfoPanel` style as below. Just check if this is how you want?

```
.InfoPanel 
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the other way, change `.Content` css

```
.Content {
overflow: auto;
background: #f1f1f1;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
top: 30px; /* .Header's height */
left: 0px;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/u0398kc1/11/